# Right cosets of the cyclic subgroup in $A_5$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Here's a homework question in Abstract Algebra that I have some troubles solving.

Given that permutation $\sigma=(1 2 4)(1 5 2)$, and $\sigma\subset A_5$. Find the number of right cosets of the cyclic subgroup $<\sigma>$ in $A_5$.

I think permutation $\sigma=(1 2 4)(1 5 2)$ can be written as $(1 5 4)$, but I'm having trouble seeing the cyclic subgroup $<(1 5 4)>$ in $A_5$, and also the right cosets of cyclic subgroup in this case.

Does it have something to do with the length of the cyclic subgroup? Thanks.

Comment: To figure out what $\langle\sigma\rangle$, you may want to calculate $\sigma^k$ for small values of $k$. To calculate the number of right cosets, it helps a lot to know Lagrange's Theorem. Do you know what that is?

Comment: @JoeyZou would you look at that, it's the big JZ!

Comment: @JoeyZou The order of the subgroup $\langle\sigma\rangle$ is a divisor of the order of $A_5$?

Comment: @advagb Yes, and it says more. Specifically, that if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then the index of $H$, i.e. the number of cosets, is equal to $|G|/|H|$.

Comment: @Nitin somehow I felt like I'd run into you at some point on SE :)

Comment: @JoeyZou Thanks a lot! But I'm still having trouble figuring out $\langle\sigma\rangle$ in $A_5$. Could you be a little bit more specific? Thanks!

Comment: Take $<\sigma>$ and compose $<\sigma> \circ \text{ } \tau$ for all $\tau \in A_{5}$.

Comment: Hint for calculating $\langle\sigma\rangle$ (or at least its size, which is what's important here): What is the order of $\sigma$? (And how does that help?)

Comment: @JoeyZou I think it's 3, because $\sigma=(154)$, but I'm not sure though..

Comment: The order of $\sigma$ is indeed $3$. And so...

Comment: @JoeyZou According to your suggestion earlier, I tried to calculate $\sigma^2=(145)$, but I can't figure what $\sigma^3$ is :(

Comment: @JoeyZou Oh! Is that I need to know the order of group G which in this case is the order of $A_{5}$?

Comment: @JoeyZou So the order of $A_{5}$ is 60, and the order of $\sigma$ is 3, therefore by Lagrange's Theorem $|G|/|H|=60/3=20$?

Comment: You got the answer! But you should understand why we're using these numbers. The reason why is because $|\langle \sigma\rangle| = 3$. In general, if the order of $\sigma$ is $k$, then $\langle\sigma\rangle = \{1,\sigma,\sigma^2,\dots,\sigma^{k-1}\}$. (You should check this fact.) BTW, you should find that $\sigma^3$ is the identity since the order of $\sigma$ is $3$.

Comment: @JoeyZou OK! Will check! Thanks so much:)